# How to build linux/amd64 golang executable with golang docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, go

I have one AWS server running ubuntu in architecture

```
arch
x86_64
```

and ubuntu version

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
```

I have a local machine in arm64 using as CI machine. I want to automate the compilation of go executable, then I ship it via ftp to the server machine.

Right now I am doing the following:

```
docker container run --rm --entrypoint='' \
    --platform linux/amd64 \
    -v ~/Desktop/dl_api:/usr/src/app \
    -w /usr/src/app \
    golang:1.18.3-alpine /bin/sh -c 'go build -o start main.go'
```

and get the executable `start` created locally. So far, all good.

I upload this to the target server, and while trying to execute that on the remote server I get the error

```
No such file or directory
```

I know that this might happen in case of different architectures or 32 64 bit etc.

To verify I run `file` command and got:

```
 file start
d-s: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, Go BuildID=jRqecrUNY3eBsSA951ei/ZZc4L0wFJ5opPN5rzoB5/XSBZzvQIfKH3hal5Dwa1/i-7Fctngr_y415-Qw_UB, not stripped
```

What can be the issue here, how can I fix this problem so that my compiled binary runs on target server?

If you notice my command, I am already specifying in docker run command the platform
`--platform linux/amd64 \`. I want to compile against amd64 and be able to run under ubuntu 20.04

Update:
As some of you suggested, I also added env variables during build like

```
    -e GOOS=linux \
    -e GOARCH=amd64 \
```

and still have same issue.

Comment: You built an Alpine-specific image but you're trying to run it on a system running a more normal Linux distribution, maybe Ubuntu.  Can you either keep this all inside Docker (`docker build` an image, `docker push` it to ECR, and `docker run` it on the target system) or not use Docker at all (`go build` a binary using a host-based Go toolchain)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I do that currently, running `go build` inside server machine and works great. For learning and automation purposes I want to build the binary before then ship via ftp to remote server.

Comment: Part 2 of what @David Maze says is what about just building the executable on your development machine (without docker). You can run the `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o start main.go` on an arm64 machine and then copy the binary to your server.

Comment: I will try that to build without docker

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with building a container with the run command like that, but I think you just need to specify the architecture as part of your `go build` command, like this:

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o start main.go
```

That's how you build a binary for a specific architecture outside of docker.

In the context of your docker command:

```
docker container run --rm --entrypoint='' \
    --platform linux/amd64 \
    -v ~/Desktop/dl_api:/usr/src/app \
    -w /usr/src/app \
    golang:1.18.3-alpine /bin/sh -c 'env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o start main.go'
```

I don't think that the `--platform linux/amd64` is required. That's specifying the platform that the container will run on (from [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/), "Set platform if server is multi-platform capable")

There's a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-go-executables-for-multiple-platforms-on-ubuntu-16-04) here that talks about building cross platform in more detail.

Comment: When I don't add the --platform flag the docker container runs in arm64. I will try your answer setting the env

Comment: I just edited my answer because I think you will need to set both `GOOS=linux` and `GOARCH=amd64`.

Comment: Thanks tried that. Still same error very frustrating ` ./start 
bash: ./start: No such file or directory
` And if i check file info ` file start 
start: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, Go BuildID=jRqecrUNY3eBsSA951ei/ZZc4L0wFJ5opPN5rzoB5/XSBZzvQIfKH3hal5Dwa1/i-7Fctngr_y415-Qw_UB, not stripped
`

Comment: (You can use `docker run -e` to directly specify an environment variable, without using env(1).  This invocation doesn't need a `sh -c` wrapper.)